# Tag helpers not working since upgrading to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

After upgrading from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 some of my forms render/print HTML form tags without the target action URL, even though the route name and route values are supplied, and it used to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because one of the needed routing values is missing and ASP.NET Core 3.1 no longer uses ambient routing values (values from the current request's routing values).

> Ambient values (route parameters from the current context) are not automatically used in link generation with endpoint routing. Previously, when generating a link to another action (or page), unspecified route values would be inferred from the current routes ambient values. When using endpoint routing, all route parameters must be specified explicitly during link generation.

You may not have realised that you didn't populate all the needed routing values to make your link, because in 2.2 it would have used the ambient ones, patching your mistake.